# Renaming '_next' to 'next' in the out directory: NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building NextJS chrome extension, the problem that I'm facing is that when I 'load unpacked' extension it say that "*Cannot load extension with file or directory name _next. Filenames starting with _ are reserved for use by the system.*"

I have checked some solutions online which says that renaming '_next' to 'next' and then changing all '_next' to 'next' in the 'out' directory should work.

the commands for the above tasks are

```
rm -rf .next/ out/
rm extension.zip 
npm run build
npm run export 
mv ./out/_next ./out/next
cd ./out && grep -rli '_next' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/_next/next/g' @ 
zip -r -FS ../my-extension.zip *
```

I have checked the above commands but it changes my styles and routing doesn't work after that.

before changing '_next' to 'next' my extension looks like this in the browser
[image]

after moving '_next' to 'next' in the 'out' directory,

```
mv ./out/_next ./out/next
```

my extension looks like this in the browser.

[image]

**Note**: I know that i have to change all the chunks which include '_next' to 'next' in the 'out' directory, but I don't know how to do that, because when I run

```
cd ./out && grep -rli '_next' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/_next/next/g' @
```

the output it gives me is:

```
$ cd ./out && grep -rli '_next' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/_next/next/g' @
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/_next/next/g: No such file or directory
```

kindly guide me, how can I rename all '_next*' to 'next*' in the this directory.

**Thank you for your precious time.**

Comment: What did you tried, what worked, what didn't ?

Comment: This isn't what I asked, we're not here to code for you but to help you when you encounter problems

Comment: He is not asking to code with you, he is asking on how properly rename _next folder to next, if you can give a suggestion that might be good.

Comment: it's an old question and after some time I have managed to solve it...here is the solution

"grep -rl '/_next' * | xargs sed -i 's|/_next|/next|g'"

note: the above "grep -rli '_next' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/_next/next/g' @ " this also works but only for Mac.

so in the above command it first reads the _next directory and then check it for every _next argument, and replaces all with next

Comment: @HarisAhmad Can you please post that as an Answer below?

Answer (score 0):

it's an old question and after some time I have managed to solve it...here is the solution

```
grep -rl '/_next' * | xargs sed -i 's|/_next|/next|g'
```

note: the above

```
grep -rli '_next' * | xargs -I@ sed -i '' 's/_next/next/g' @
```

this also works but only for Mac. So in the above command, it first reads the _next directory and then checks it for every '_next' argument, and replaces all with next